# cython: reducing the size of a class, reduce memory use, improve speed

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cython

I am have a relatively simple problem: given a position in the genome, return the name of the gene at that point.

The way I am solving this problem right now is using the following class in cython::

```
class BedFile():
    """ A Lookup Object """
    def __init__(self, bedfile):
        self.dict = {}
        cdef int start, end
        with open(bedfile) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                f = line.rstrip().split('\t')
                if len(f) < 4:
                    continue
                chr   = f[0]
                start = int(f[1])
                end   = int(f[2])
                gene  = f[3]
                if chr not in self.dict:
                    self.dict[chr] = {}
                self.dict[chr][gene] = (start, end)

    def lookup(self, chromosome, location):
        """ Lookup your gene. Returns the gene name """
        cdef int l
        l = int(location)
        answer = ''
        for k, v in self.dict[chromosome].items():
            if v[0] < l < v[1]:
                answer = k
                break
        if answer:
            return answer
        else:
            return None
```

The full project is here: https://github.com/MikeDacre/python_bed_lookup, although the entire relevant class is above.

The issue with the code as is is that the resulting class/dictionary take up a very large amount of memory for the human genome, with 110 million genes (that's a 110 million line long text file). I killed the **init** function in the process of building the dictionary after about two minutes, when it hit 16GB of memory. Anything that uses that much memory is basically useless.

I am sure there must me a more efficient way of doing this, but I am not a C programmer, and I am very new to cython. My guess is that I could build a pure C structure of some kind to hold the gene name and the start and end values. Then I could convert lookup() into a function that calls another cdef function called _lookup(), and use that cdef function to do that actual query.

In an ideal world, the whole structure could live in memory and take up less than 2GB of memory for ~2,000,000 entries (each entry with two ints and a string).

Edit:
I figured out how to do this efficiently with sqlite for large file, to see the complete code with sqlite see here: https://github.com/MikeDacre/python_bed_lookup

However, I still think that the class above can be optimized with cython to make the dictionary smaller in memory and lookups faster, any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Won't help on memory  but a defaultdict and the csv lib would definitely be more efficient

Comment: This sounds like a data problem, not a code problem.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Thanks, I didn't know about defaultdict, good to know. The memory issue is the main one here though. I think I can do this by using sqlite instead of keeping the object in memory, but I am still curious if there is an efficient C structure approach that would be more efficient than what I have done here.

Comment: No worries, I just thought I would mention it as it may be useful for other parts of your  lib,  I will have a better look tomorrow and see if I can come up with anything that may help the memory issue.

Comment: This is basically a file read, dictionary build and lookup.  `cython` is not going to help much, if at all, with that heavy a use of Python objects (file and dictionaries). `cython` is most useful (speed and memory) when it can convert your code into basic `C` code, without much use of Python calls.

Comment: I'd start by changing the `(start,end)` tuple for a `cdef class StartEnd: public int start, end` (with an appropriate newline). For the moment leave the dictionaries as is, since they're easy to use, difficult to replace and probably not too inefficient. You could also consider using `short int`s instead of ints.

Comment: @hpaulj That is somewhat true, but what makes this different is that it isn't a dictionary lookup really. I am looping through the dictionary like a list and doing a math operation using two ints in a tuple to choose the right answer. I think scanning a list of tuples and doing the same thing would be just as efficient, because I am not really taking advantage of the lookup capabilities of the dictionary. Really I think an ideal would be a pure C function using an array of a custom structure and looping through that. I am going to try DavidW's solution and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my limited experience with `cython` and `numpy`, it is most profitable to use `cython` for 'inner' calculations that don't need to use Python/numpy code.  They are iterations that can be cast to compact and fast C code.

Here's a rewrite of your code, splitting out two classes could be recast as Cython/C structures:

```
# cython candidate, like DavidW's StartEnd
class Gene(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.chr = values[0]
        self.start = int(values[1])
        self.end = int(values[2])
        self.gene = values[3]
    def find(self, i):
        return self.start<=i<self.end
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%s, %d:%d)"%(self.chr,self.gene,self.start,self.end)

# cython candidate
class Chrom(list):
    def add(self, aGene):
        self.append(aGene)
    def find(self, loc):
        # find - analogous to string find?
        i = int(loc)
        for gene in self:
             if gene.find(i):
                 return gene  # gene.gene
        return None
    def __repr__(self):
        astr = []
        for gene in self:
            astr += [repr(gene)]
        return '; '.join(astr)
```

These would be imported and used by a high level Python function (or class) that does not need to be in the Cython .pdx file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def load(anIterable):
    data = defaultdict(Chrom)
    for line in anIterable:
        f = line.rstrip().split(',')
        if len(f)<4:
            continue
        aGene = Gene(f)
        data[aGene.chr].add(aGene)
    return data
```

Use with a file or a text simulation:

```
# befile = 'filename'
# with open(bedfile) as infile:
#    data = load(infile)

txt = """\
A, 1,4,a
A, 4,8,b
B, 3,5,a
B, 5,10,c
"""
data = load(txt.splitlines())
print data
# defaultdict(<class '__main__.Chrom'>, {
#   'A': A(a, 1:4); A(b, 4:8),
#   'B': B(a, 3:5); B(c, 5:10)})

print 3, data['A'].find(3)   # a gene
print 9, data['B'].find(9)   # c gene
print 11,data['B'].find(11)   # none
```

I could define a `find` function that defers to a method if available, otherwise uses its own.  This is analogous to numpy functions that delegate to methods:

```
def find(chrdata, loc):
    # find - analogous to string find?
    fn = getattr(chrdata, 'find',None)
    if fn is None:
        #raise AttributeError(chrdata,'does not have find method')
        def fn(loc):
            i = int(loc)
            for gene in chrdata:
                if gene.find(i):
                    return gene  # gene.gene
            return None
    return fn(loc)

print 3, find(data['A'],3)
```

Test the `find` with an ordinary list data structure:

```
def loadlist(anIterable):
    # collect data in ordinary list
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for line in anIterable:
        f = line.rstrip().split(',')
        if len(f)<4:
            continue
        aGene = Gene(f)
        data[aGene.chr].append(aGene)
    return data

data = loadlist(txt.splitlines())
print 3, find(data['A'],3)
```

Comment: Brilliant. @DavidW's solution solved the memory issue, and this adds to that by making the lookups faster. Loading 100 million entries takes about 3 minutes and uses 10GB of memory, but lookups are instantaneous. Calling cython classes requires writing the whole thing in one pyx file, but that is fine. To deal with the slow load time for very large files, I created an sqlite3 module to handle very large files, but that is only required for files with more than 5 million lines. The final product is here: https://github.com/MikeDacre/python_bed_lookup. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my suggestion in the comments a bit, instead of storing `(start,end)` as a tuple, store it as a simple Cython-defined class:

```
cdef class StartEnd:
    cdef public int start, end

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

(you could also play with changing the integer type for more size savings). I'm not recommending getting rid of the Python dictionaries because they're easy to use, and (I believe) optimised to be reasonably efficient for the (common in Python) case of string keys.

We can estimate the rough size savings by using `sys.getsizeof`. (Be aware that this will work well for built-in classes and Cython classes, but not so well for Python classes so don't trust it too far. Also be aware that the results are platform dependent so yours may differ slightly).

```
>>> sys.getsizeof((1,2)) # tuple
64
>>> sys.getsizeof(1) # Python int
28
```

(therefore each tuple contains 64+28+28=120 bytes)

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(StartEnd(1,2)) # my custom class
24
```

(24 makes sense: it's the `PyObject_Head` (16 bytes: a 64bit integer and a pointer) + 2 32-bit integers).

Therefore, 5 times smaller, which is a good start I think.

Comment: Great, this works in principle. I did it slightly differently by using a struct instead and using c++ vectors: `cdef struct StartEnd:\n long start, end\n char* name` I then make a dictionary of vectors: `self._dict[chr] = vector[StartEnd]` `self._dict[chr].push_back(t)` where t is a StartEnd struct I made earlier. This is currently a third the size of my initial solution. Do you think that makes sense, or is using a `cdef class` better? I think having one dictionary is also fine, as the first dictionary only has 23 entries and dictionary lookup is efficient for those.

Comment: So you don't need that inner `gene` level dictionary.  You could just as well use a tuple `(gene, start, stop)` or some `C` equivalent (class or structure).

Comment: If you don't need the inner level dictionary (as hpaulj says) then your solution comfortably beats mine. Mine was picked as something that would get a decent(ish) improvement with minimal changes, but it still uses 2/3 of its space on Python bookkeeping. The advantage to a `cdef class` vs a `struct` is that you can use it directly from Python, but if you don't need that then use a `struct`.

Comment: I will look at hpaulj's solution below in a minute, but I can confirm that by using the method here I can read a 10 million line file into about 1GB of memory and a 100 million line long file into ~8GB of memory. Compared to nearly 4GB of memory for a 5 million line long file in my solution. The process is still slow: 6 minutes for 100 million lines. The lookup is also a little slow right now. Not sure if hpaulj's solution will help with that.